# SpringMVCの画面遷移について

Tags: java, spring

(java)
Eclipse4.6上でSpringSTSを利用してJava Webソフトを開発しています。
最初のログイン画面から次のメニューに遷移する際にjspは実行してくれるのですが
これに対応したControllerクラスのGETメソットを実行してくれません。
タイトル用の画像をはめ込むだけですが
なぜControllクラスに遷移しないのか不明です。
関連のソースを以下に示します。

<ログインコントロール>

```
package jp.vikingegg.VESales.control;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import jp.vikingegg.VESales.common.EnvironmentInfo;
import jp.vikingegg.VESales.service.LoginService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class LoginController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    public LoginController(){

        loginService = new LoginService();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogin(Locale locale, Model model) {

        logger.info("VikingEgg(LoginGET)  The client locale is {}.", locale);

        // 実行ユーザー情報クリア
        loginService.userInfoClear();

        // システム情報設定
        EnvironmentInfo environmentInfo = new EnvironmentInfo();
        model.addAttribute("systemImage",environmentInfo.getSystemImage());
        model.addAttribute("systemName",environmentInfo.getSystemName());

        String wView = "Login";


        return wView;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postLogin(@RequestParam("userid") String pUserId,
                             @RequestParam("password") String password,
                             Locale locale,
                             Model model) {

        try{

            logger.info("Login VikingEgg(LoginPOST)  The client locale is {}.", locale);


            String userId = pUserId;
            String pass = password;

            String retForm = "";

            // 入力エラーメッセージクリア
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage","");

            retForm = "/";


            loginService.GetUserInfo(userId, pass);


            String ErrMsg = loginService.UserIDCheck();

            if (ErrMsg == ""){

                // メニュー
                retForm = loginService.getMenu();


            }else{

                // 入力エラー
                model.addAttribute("errorMessage",ErrMsg);
                logger.info("nextMenu : " + retForm);

                retForm = "/";


            }

            //retForm = "forward:" + "AMenuController";
            logger.info("Login VikingEgg(NextMenu) = " + retForm, locale);


            return retForm;


        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.info("Login(POST) "+ e.toString()   , locale);


            return "";
        }


    }

}
```

<ログインから遷移するメニューのコントロールクラス>

```
package jp.vikingegg.VESales.control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import jp.vikingegg.VESales.common.EnvironmentInfo;
import jp.vikingegg.VESales.common.GlobalConst;
import jp.vikingegg.VESales.service.AMenuservice;

@Controller
public class AMenuController  {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AMenuController.class);

    @Autowired
    private AMenuservice amenuService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/AMenu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAMenu(Locale locale, Model model) throws IOException{

        logger.info("AMenu(GET)  The client locale is {}.", locale);

        try{

            logger.info("AMenu(GET)  AMenuGET", locale);


            // システム情報設定
            EnvironmentInfo environmentInfo = new EnvironmentInfo();
            model.addAttribute("systemImage",environmentInfo.getSystemImage());
            model.addAttribute("systemName",environmentInfo.getSystemName());

            String wView = GlobalConst.cnsMenuAdmin;
            return wView;

        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.info("AMenu(GET)  Error {"+ e.toString() + "}", locale);

            String wView = GlobalConst.cnsLogin;
            return wView;

        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/AMenu", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ModelAndView postAMenu(Locale locale, Model model){

        ModelAndView wView = new ModelAndView(GlobalConst.cnsMenuAdmin);
        return wView;


    }

}
```

<メニューのJSP>

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>${systemName}（管理者メニュー）</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/comm/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- 全画面共通スタイル -->
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/comm/projectcomm/common.css" />" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

        <!-- ADMINメニュー画面のスタイル -->
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/AMenu.css" />" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/jquery/jquery.min.js" />" ></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" />" ></script>


    </head>
    <body>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                   <img class="profile-img" src="<c:url value="${systemImage}"/>" alt="">
            </div>
               <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                <font>${systemName1}</font>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="AMenu" name="FormAMenu" method="post">
            <div class="center-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <ul id="dropmenu">
                          <li><a href="">ログアウト</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">システム管理</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="SystemEnv">システム環境</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">バッチスケジューラー</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">採番管理</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">エラーメッセージ管理</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">バックアップ</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">ユーザー管理</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">会社登録</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">組織登録</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">社員ユーザ登録</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">統計処理</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">アクセス解析</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">バックアップ</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">データバックアップ</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">環境保存</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="center-block">
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

コントローラーの戻り値で文字列を指定した場合、通常はViewのパスを指定した事になります。

コントローラーから他のコントローラーへ遷移させたい場合はフォワードを使用します。
フォワードを使用するには、戻り値の文字列に`forward:`を付けます。

AMenuControllerクラスのgetAMenu()のパスはRequestMappingで`/AMenu`となっているので、ここに遷移させたいのなら`forward:/AMenu`を戻り値にしてください。

ただしフォワードを使用した場合はブラウザに表示されるURLのパスは元のコントローラのパス(今回の場合は`/`)になります。

ブラウザに表示されるURLを遷移先コントローラのパスにしたい場合は、`redirect:`でリダイレクトを使用します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。　「forword:/AMenu」もやってみたのですが、状態はかわらずjspのみで困っています。

Comment: 元のコントローラーがPOSTなのでpostAMenu()が呼ばれているのではないでしょうか？
postAMenu()が呼ばれているのか確認して下さい。
getAMenu()を呼びたいのであればredirect:を試してみてください。

Comment: ご指摘の通りPOSTが呼ばれていました GETを呼ぶにはどうすればよいのでしょうか

Comment: すみません。しっかり読まないで回答してしまいました..fredirect:も試してみます

Comment: リターンに「fredirect:/AMenu」
とは言っていますが４０４のエラーでした。とりあえす、POSTで行きます